# Sauter - idiomatic meanings

Tags: anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

> Donnez au croupier la possibilité de sauter tout seul !

This use of 'sauter' seems to imply an idiomatic meaning, something like *get himself in a fix*, or *give himself a length of rope*

Or does it simply mean 'carry out a move'?

(This is in reference to gaming, no connection to the slang *sauter qqn*)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the context is related to the Blackjack, *sauter* means being busted, i.e. exceed 21.